# Adding text Macros to an editor

Tags: editors

I want to add global macros to my `TeX` editor. By this, I mean something like this: every time I write `\section{x}`, it automatically adds `\label{sec:x}` after `\section{x}`.

Is it possible on `Texmaker`? If not, is there another ``` Windows``TeX ``` editor which allows these kinds of things?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't do this, section titles can contain formatting that doesn't work in labels, and a major idea of `\label` is that it is a stable internal identifier that you can use that does not change even if you renumber or edit the section title. Your editor macro may seem to save a fraction of time to type `\label{foo}` but if you then have to edit the whole document to change every `\ref` when you edit a title, it is time lost.

Comment: I basically want to add \label{thm:}, \label{prop:} \label{dfn:} automatically each time I add any of these environments. This does save time. I can then manually insert an internal name.

Comment: that's reasonable (and what emacs editor does by default) but is not what you asked for (or what you got as an answer)

Comment: When I asked my question I had in mind the snippet below. I still want to use it.

Comment: @omar For texstudio (originally a texmaker fork, so very similar in usage) you can use https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Scripts#automatic-label-creation-by-pressing-space-after-a-structure-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution with VS Code

You can use the [user snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets). In the specific case as you have said, you can write a snippet as follows:

```json
  "section":{
    "prefix": "sec",
    "body": "\\section{$1}\\label{sec:$1}\n\n",
    "description": "Insert Section Command",
  }
```

into `latex.json`. Then insert `sec` to trigger the snippet:

[image]

But for some long section title, it's inappropriate to set the label the same as section name. So it's better to substitute the second `$1` with `$2`. This way one can give section name and label name separately.

Comment: hmm `\section{I \emph{wonder} if this is a good idea:-)}`

Comment: @Stephen Thank you very much. It work perfectly !

Comment: @omar See my updated version.

Comment: This solution given can be used, or not, so this is an excellent tip even if I have decided to use `VSCodium`. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In emacs (auctex) this is set up by default.

[image]

`C-c C-s`  then triggers a prompt

[image]

hit `<return>`

prompts for title

[image]

it then prompts for (optional) label, discarding it if you just hit return)

[image]

So producing

[image]

From the keystrokes

`C-cC-s<return>hello world<return>foo<return>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

[Gummi](https://gummi.app/) is a simple LateX editor but in menu <kbd>Edit</kbd>→<kbd>Preferences</kbd> allow to define code snippets as this:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=${1:1.0}]{$2}
\caption{$3}
\label{$4}
\end{figure}
$0
```

Typing anywhere `img`<kbd>Tab</kbd> in the document, this code will be pasted As is, except the variables `$0` to `$4`. The variable $1 have a default value,  so `${1:1.0}` will appear as `1.0` and selected automatically, while the othes will be empty (`{$2}` will appear as `{}`, and so on). As you start with the value of $1 selected, typing some like  `0.3`<kbd>Tab</kbd> will change the default image scale and jump to `$2` position. So, to complete the whole snippet, you can type some like `example-image` <kbd>Tab</kbd> `My caption` <kbd>Tab</kbd> `mylabel`<kbd>Tab</kbd> `I am now in main text ...`

The final resul will be:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}
\caption{My caption}
\label{mylabel}
\end{figure}
I am now in main text ...▎
```

Note: the ▎symbol represent the final cursor, not any real  character. Do not copy this chunk of code in a document compiled with pdflatex, or you will obtain the `LaTeX Error: Unicode character ▎ (U+258E) not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Of course, you can edit the snippets to add for instance `fig:` to labels of figures automatically, or make your own new snippet of whatever code and call it with `whatever`<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Some predefined snippets already make label types added automatically. For example `sec`<kbd>Tab</kbd> will call to:

```
\section{${1:section name}}
\label{sec:${2}}
$0
% section $2 (end)
```

Therefore, `sec` <kbd>Tab</kbd> `mysection`<kbd>Tab</kbd> `foo`<kbd>Tab</kbd> `My nice text ...` will produce:

```
\section{mysection}
\label{sec:foo}
My nice text ... 
% section foo (end)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

One could also use AutoHotKey for this purpose. Then you are independent of editors, and can even sync the script to different computers to have the same shortcuts everywhere in every editor. To produce a section with label command, a possible solution would be:

```
:*:c#::\chapter{{} {}} {RETURN}\label{{}sec: {}}
```

With this, you can type

```
c#
```

, which will be replaced to

```
\chapter{ } 
\label{sec: }
```

I do a similar thing for references in texstudio, were I also trigger the autocomplete function of texstudio by simulating further keyboard input. To insert a symbol with glossaries package, the following code creates the command to reference to the symbol and start the auto complete dropdown when I type `sym#`:

```
:*:sym#::\gls{{}sym:{}}{LEFT}{Ctrl down}{Space}{Ctrl up}
```

Produces:

```
\gls{sym:}
```

In TeXstudio, it looks like this:
[image: Symbol insert]

This could be adapted to all other references, like bibliographies or your other labels.

I believe all this is possible in TeXstudio (a fork of TeXmaker) with its built in scripting language, but I rarely use this.

Edit:
Actually, I found an example script for TeXstudio on their script gallery. You can find it here:
https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio-macro/blob/555dffe7aef3d0433fdcf1784b7ef057c4ee8ec5/automatedTextmanipulation/autoLabel.txsMacro

This does exactly what you asked for, but I did not test it.